# Why won't my RequiredValidator work inside this Jquery dialog box?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, jquery-ui

I have a dialog box that boxes that allows the user to do enter some texts in before submitting to server. The text is mandatory.

My code looks like this

This is the Jquery code to open up the dialog

```
     function onReportThis() {
     $("#dialog-Report").dialog({
         resizable: false,
         modal: true,
         width: '400px',
         buttons: {
             Submit: function () {

                 __doPostBack('<%= lnkReportThis.UniqueID %>', '');

                 //                     onReported();
             },
             Cancel: function () {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
             }
         }
     });
     $("#dialog-Report").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    return false;
}
```

This is the code for the box itself.

```
    <div id="dialog-Report" style="display: none" title="Report This Profile">
    <p>
        I am reporting this profile because</p>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="validReportText" ControlToValidate="txtReportDetail" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter text" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <p>
        Please enter additional details regarding why you are reporting this profile</p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtReportDetail" runat="server" Width="300px" Height="300px" TextMode="MultiLine" />
</div>
```

The required field validator is not being used before the callback. How do I get this to work? Thank you

UPDATE : I've got it working.

I had to do this.

```
                     if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
                     __doPostBack('<%= lnkReportThis.UniqueID %>', '');
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend, you are in a world of hurt... but to answer your question, you need to manually fire the validation events before you call the `__dosubmit()` method.

This article explains how you can do this client side: http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2009/07/aspnet-how-to-trigger-client-side.html

Essentially, you want to call `Page_ClientValidate();` before you submit

Comment: It turns out you are right. I didn't realize the DoPostback did not automatically validate it. I've used the Page_ClientValidate() method and it works. thanks!